# Proposta de edição com o objetivo de reescrever uma tag já existente, o que fazer?

Tags: suporte, comportamento, edições-sugeridas

Esta foi  análise que apareceu:

<kbd>[image: análise]</kbd>

Como podem ver, a única mudança foi a inclusão da tag.

A tag [go](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/go) até então nem existia, acho que ela foi criada no momento em que o usuário enviou essa proposta de edição. Dúvidas referentes à linguagem do Google utilizam a [golang](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/golang) — que inclusive tem o mesmo nome do site [**golang**](http://golang.org/).

O que fazer quando a proposta de edição tem somente o objetivo de reescrever de forma diferente uma tag já existente? Por exemplo: Java-8 e java8, no final das contas é Java. JS é Javascript.

A principio pensei em permitir e depois sugerir um sinônimo para a tag mas fiquei com receio do céu cair sob a minha cabeça por ser uma edição mínima, isto é, o uso de [golang](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/golang) já deixa claro sobre qual linguagem é a dúvida do AP. Também me pareceu uma tag genérica demais, embora "go" seja o nome da linguagem. E pareceu também que eu estaria concordando em duplicar um tema que já existe.

Poderiam me instruir ao que fazer na próxima vez que aparecer esse tipo de análise? Quais ações devo tomar?

Comment: Em relação à tua pergunta: "O que fazer quando a proposta de edição tem somente o objetivo de reescrever de forma diferente uma tag já existente?" eu diria que é caso de rejeitar. Pode contudo ser caso de adicionar um novo sinónimo.

Comment: Aí que está: Qual das duas opções?

Comment: As duas :) uma de cada vez. Rejeitar e depois se a tag fôr um sinónimo válido [criar um novo](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/admin/create-tag-synonym) . Minha opinião....

Comment: Eu tentaria analisar as contribuições anteriores do editor antes de tomar a decisão de rejeitar ou aprovar.

Comment: Concordo com o @Sergio

Comment: @Gabe, o SO usa [tag:go] como  [tag principal](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/go/info), sendo `golang` e `go-language` redirecionadas para lá. Inclusive parece uma tag patrocinada, é isso mesmo que significa uma tag com ícone?